# How to view the Scss's @debug result in vscode or in browser dev tools?

Tags: sass, live-sass-compiler

How can I watch **@debug** result in scss?

I'm using the **Live Sass Compiler** by **Glenn Marks** in VSCode. Is there a way I can see the debug output in the terminal or chrome console?

Code example:

```
@debug 'hello world';
@debug math.div(10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to set `showOutputWindowOn` to `Debug`. You can see details in the [settings](https://github.com/glenn2223/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md#livesasscompilesettingsshowoutputwindowon)

Answer (score 1):

More specifically (*as from another answer pointed out*); (in multiple diff ways)::

- |-| `ctrl+shift+p` > `Preferences: Open Settings (UI)` (`workbench.action.openSettings2`) > Workspace > Live Sass Compile > Settings: Show Output Window On > Debug
- |-| `ctrl+shift+p` > `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)` (`workbench.action.openWorkspaceSettingsFile`) > paste `"liveSassCompile.settings.showOutputWindowOn": "Debug"`
- |-| `ctrl+shift+p` > exec `liveSass.command.showOutputOn.debug`
- |-| (or you may use comments as an output, as a workaround...)

<sub>> Reference::
>
> [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75055821/95490680)
>
> https://github.com/glenn2223/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md#livesasscompilesettingsshowoutputwindowon
>
> https://github.com/glenn2223/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md#livesasscommandshowoutputon
>
> https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/issues/234#issuecomment-762474594 (outdated?)</sub>